# Invalid source error when trying to add citations in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, cross-reference, mendeley

I am uploading an XML file produced by `Mendeley` to an MS word file. Even though I have all the information correctly saved including authors names and journal details, the Word disregard the authors names.

[image]

In fact, when I look at the details of the spesific citation, I can see that Word warns me about invalid source. I checked the trust settings and there seems to be no problem.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try it [in Word safe mode](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-office-apps-in-safe-mode-on-a-windows-pc-dedf944a-5f4b-4afb-a453-528af4f7ac72). Which Office version are you using?

Comment: @harrymc It is Word 16. I'll give it a try for the safe mode and let you know

Comment: @harrymc I opened the Word file in the safe mode, but it still says that "invalid source spesficied" for each citation that I add.

Comment: Try in Trust Center to place check-marks to trust everything.

Comment: @harrymc are you referring to File Block Settings? If so, putting a check mark blocks the file type. Also, in the safe mode, Trust Settings are disabled.

Comment: @harrymc I enabled all the macros. I disabled trusted documents. Interestingly, If I update the citations type from journal article to a report, then it kinda works

Comment: This has some kind of twisted logic. Try to set in the "Edit source" dialog "Show All Bibliography Fields", to check for surprises.

Comment: @harrymc I've done it and nothing unsusal :/

Comment: Try perhaps to create XML from a citation that worked, and compare the XML with the one generated by Mendeley. See [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/word/concepts/working-with-word/working-with-bibliographies).

Comment: Just  looking at the screenshots that you posted, AFAIK you have to *copy* the sources that you need into the "Current List" before they become usable in the current document. i.e. even though you may be able to see a citation tag in the entry, a CITATION in the document with that tag will fail with "Invalid Source Specified" unless you do that copy. But that certainly doesn't explain why you are seeing such messages in the Citation Preview box.

Comment: @jonsson I have already done that. When I insert the citation after copying, I see the invalid source warning in the main text file.